# Node express (typescript) | serialize date type as epoach ms globally

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I wish to configure my node based API back-end, to serialize all of Date types as Epoch millis instead of ISO.

for example, if I have the following interface:

```
export interface Profile {
    updatedAt: Date;
    updatedBy: string;
}
```

and when I'm returning my struct back to the client:

```
 return res.status(OK).json(myProfile);
```

I get the following response:

```
   "updatedAt": "2021-06-08T17:06:44.412Z",
   "updatedBy": "825e9b827ce329a7ddc8fbdc3f714cbd1c239182"
```

I wish to receive:

```
   "updatedAt":  1623172004412,
   "updatedBy": "825e9b827ce329a7ddc8fbdc3f714cbd1c239182"
```

and to do it once, globally for all of my endpoints
any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this for *any field*, for *any object*, you could define a new function:

```js
let customJSON = (obj) => {
    Object.entries(obj).map(([k,v]) => v instanceOf Date && (obj[k] = new Date(v).getTime()));
    return obj;
}
```

Then register this function in Express as middleware:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const originalSON = res.json
    res.json = (status, data) => {
        originalSON.call(res, customJSON(data));
    }
    next();
});
```

This should require no change to your call site:

```js
return res.status(OK).json(myProfile);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but solution is solving my problem for a specific class definition, and I'm looking for a global solution for all of Date types.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.
I do have another question, does the JSON function is executing twice? 
once for ISO and than Epoch millis?

Comment: not quite, `customJSON` just directly edits the object date fields, and then returns the edited object. The edited object then gets passed to `res.json` which handles it as usual.